# PHP - Collecting ID from previous page

Tags: php, html, sql

One page in my root directory, displays text collected from the database.

This page has a uniquely generated ID. A link on this page redirects the user to another page in the same root directory. On this second page I need to collect the specific ID (/URL) from the previous page, and use it as a variable.

How can I do this as smooth as possible?

Can I "send" the ID value from one page to the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the page you're linking from..

```
<href="http://www.yoursiteurl.com/yournewpage.php?passedInId=<?php echo $theIdToCarryOver; ?>">link text</a>
```

In yournewpage.php, cast your value to an integer to make sure the receiving page always gets an integer

```
$id = intval($_GET['passedInId']);
```

Comment: Why do I need: <?php echo $theIdToCarryOver; ?> ?

Comment: This is the value to pass on to the next page as part of the query string. $theIdToCarryOver was just an arbitrary variable name. Use whatever variable you want to put in its place

Answer (score 3):

You could set the value in a session variable for use later.

```
// Start the session
session_start();

// ID variable generated
$generated_id = 12345;

// Create the session variable
$_SESSION['id'] = $generated_id;
```

Then on the second page retrieve the variable

```
// Start the session
session_start();

// Retrieve the variable
$generated_id = $_SESSION['id'];

echo $generated_id;

// Destroy session (if desired)
unset($_SESSION['id']);
```

Comment: what exactly is wrong with this answer? as i believe saving the id in a session var is far more neat than passing it on in the get var (ie. what happens when a user changes the id in the url...)

Comment: @giorgio Thank's giorgio, I agree with you, it is neater.  Feel free to vote it up :)

Comment: only if you delete the OR part of your answer :p you've got the up!

Comment: The changes have been made :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, just append it to the URL as a parameter

```
www.mysite.com/?id=1
```

or

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?id=1;
```

And in the page (might be index.php) you retrieve it with $_GET superglobal:

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
```

Or even better, we check if the array key is set before calling it:

```
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? intval($_GET['id']) : '0';
```

Here I made sure the id was numeric. You should always check / escape if necessary according to medium what you retrieve from the outside, like in this case.

You can appen any other value after this, just add an ampersand(&) instead.

```
www.mysite.com/index.php?id=1&page=2

$id = $_GET['id'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by using the [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a `<input type="hidden" id="uniquestring" value="yourvalue">`

Then using get/post you have an array key  $_POST["uniquestring"] whichs value is "yourvalue"

Edit: of course, this is just for non-private information, cuz it can be viewed in source though.
For security reason i'd prefer a session solution as mentioned